# Fetch-API referrer issues (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, automation, fetch-api

I have a problem with retaining full referrer url with the pathname. I might set it to
example.com/thread/123.html
but instead the server gets just `example.com`

Here's an example:

```
    const jsdom = require("jsdom");
    fetch("https://www.httpdebugger.com/Tools/ViewBrowserHeaders.aspx",{referrer: "https://www.httpdebugger.com/Tools/"
    ,credentials: 'include', mode: 'cors', referrerPolicy: "no-referrer"}).catch(err => console.log(err))
    .then(function(result) {
        return result.text()
    }).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result)
    });
```

This returns

`div class='col-sm-2'>Referer https://www.httpdebugger.com/</div><`

Instead of https://www.httpdebugger.com/Tools/ like you would get if you got from that url manually.

I understand that this is probably because the request isn't same origin, but I don't understand how can I fix it. Strangely fetch seems to ignore referrerPolicy altogether even if you set it to "no-referrer".

Should I just switch to another library? This wasn't a problem with XMLHttpRequest, but then again it's a browser library.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#referrer: _"This can be a same-origin URL, `about:client`, or an empty string."_ - so I think what you intend to do there, _should not_ work to begin with.

Comment: `referrerPolicy: "no-referrer"` would result in NO referrer header at all

Comment: Thanks, turns out fetch is not an option. Axios works perfectly, on the other hand. Should've checked the docs. Also it did result in a referrer header when I tested it. (exact same code as in the body of the question)